# La operación de múltiples pasos de Ole Db generó errores. Compruebe los valores de estado de Ole Db si es posible

Tags: c#, ms-access

Al momento de insertar los datos desde Visual Studio a Access me encuentro con este error.
Me podrían explicar de qué trata y cómo corregirlo.
El siguiente fragmento de código es mi botón para insertar los datos.
private void btnCrearReporte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
   try
   {
       var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOC_C_.Properties.Settings.old_noc_databaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
       using (OleDbConnection Conector = new OleDbConnection(conString))
       {

           Conector.Open();
         
           string query = "INSERT INTO reporte (fuente_reporte, fecha_incidente, fecha_notificacion, sitio_equipo, evento, tipo_evento, detalle_evento, tipo_trabajo, agente_monitoreo, encargado_ly)  VALUES (@fuente_reporte, @fecha_incidente, @fecha_notificacion, @sitio_equipo, @evento, @tipo_evento, @detalle_evento, @tipo_trabajo, @agente_monitoreo,@encargado_ly);";
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, Conector);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuente_reporte", CMBMedioDeReporte.SelectedItem);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_incidente", DateIncidente.Value);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_notificacion", DateNotificacion.Value);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitio_equipo", Int64.Parse(CMBEquipoFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@evento", CMBTituloFrm.SelectedItem);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_evento", Int64.Parse(CMBTipoFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalle_evento", txtDetalle.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_trabajo", CMBTipoDeTrabajo.SelectedItem);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agente_monitoreo", Int64.Parse(CMBAgenteDeMonitoreo.SelectedValue.ToString()));
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@encargado_ly", Int64.Parse(CMBEncargadoLYFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


       }

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
```

}

Comment: Es el mismo codigo con otro codigo de error.. en este caso, segui depurando.. es mas.. te recomendaria que en lugar de probar con todos los campos, vayas agregando los campos de a uno, a ver cual te genera el error... no tiene sentido otra pregunta igual, por mas que el codigo de error alla cambiado...